# How to loop the array of items by two and put to another array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

Here's how I made my array:

```
var data = [];
$('tbody > tr','#iddetails').each(function(){
    var idtype   = $('.input-IDtype',this).val();
    var idnumber = $('.input-IDnumber',this).val();
    data.push(idtype, idnumber);
});
```

**Output:**

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want my newdata array should be like this output:

```
newdata = [

[0] 1,2

[1] 3,4

[2] 5,6

]
```

How can I make my newdata array looks like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a simple modification on your original code can generate your expected new array:

```
var data = [];

$('tbody > tr','#iddetails').each(function()
{
    var idtype   = $('.input-IDtype',this).val();
    var idnumber = $('.input-IDnumber',this).val();

    // Note here we push a new array with the pair [idtype, idnumber]
    // into data array.
    data.push([idtype, idnumber]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) like

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const newData = data.reduce((memo, val, i, originalData) => {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    memo.push(originalData.slice(i, i + 2))
  };
  return memo;
}, [])

console.log(newData);
```